# Is there any good tool to manage bash history?

Tags: linux, bash, history

Wanting to remember some impotant cmds, I used to put them in .bashrc_history file and use search to find, like:

```
$ history | grep alias | grep coffee | grep code
```

but sometimes history may lost for some reason. Also, usually several terminals, which may rewrite the history.. So is there any tool to manage?

Comment: Put them in a separate textfile instead that is not limited by $HISTSIZE?

Comment: Please have a look at this related [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/80371/5014).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this into your `~/.bashrc` and re-login (or source the ~/.bashrc)

```
prompt_command() {
    history | sed '$!d' >> /path/to/some/file
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Now every command you type will be appended to `/path/to/some/file` immediately after you type it

Comment: `prompt_command() {
    echo google >> /path/to/some/file ; history -a | sed -n '$p' >> /path/to/some/file
}` this piece of code wrote "google" to my myfile.. seems strange.

Comment: Because you told it to with `echo google >> /path/to/some/file`.  Why are you putting that in there?

Comment: I found that file stays empty after I putting the codes in ~/.bashrc , so I want to see that function was invocked or not by adding `echo goo..`. The result is that function is called many times, but no history was wrriten there. Just a test.

Comment: @jiyinyiyong sorry, it should have been just `history` and not `history -a`.  I updated my answer, it should work now. I also made the `sed` command just a slight bit shorter.